# Excel macro trying to make changes after macro is finished and worksheet is locked

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I protect an Excel document from being edited since users keep breaking it.

While this Excel document shouldn't be broken this easily; it is outside my scope to fix it. I am here to provide a temporary solution.

**The issue**
When users execute the refresh macro it locks the worksheet too fast; in turn it gives an error that it can't make changes since the cell or chart is protected.
The module for locking the sheet gets executed at the end.

**My Code**

```vb
Sub Verversen()
'
' Verversen Macro
'
Call Module11.unlockcells
    Range("J12").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch Checker").ListObjects("AllStockSQL").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch Checker").ListObjects("AllStockSQL").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AllStockSQL[[#Headers],[#Data],[Batch]]"), SortOn _
        :=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch Checker").ListObjects("AllStockSQL").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
'Call Module12.Refresh_All_Data_Connections
'   Range("G31").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotCache.Refresh
'   ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Call Module9.lockcells
End Sub
```

**Module 9**

```vb
Public Sub lockcells()

Worksheets("Batch Checker").Range("F4:N200").Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="temp", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True

End Sub
```

**Module 11**

```vb
Public Sub unlockcells()

ActiveSheet.UNprotect Password:="temp"
Worksheets("Batch Checker").Range("F4:N200").Locked = False

End Sub
```

I tried a wait timer;
I turned off the background refresh except option Refresh this connection on Refresh All;
I tried to put `DoEvents` before;
I tried creating different modules which I'd call in.

Comment: Why for Range("F4:N200") use the Worksheets("Batch Checker") and for  UNprotect/Protect use ActiveSheet ? Are you sure the ActiveSheet is the sheet you want ?

Comment: I've just changed that all to specifically use worksheet Batch checker and it still gives the same error sadly.

Comment: While debugging (F8) in whitch line of code fires the error?

Comment: Did you try calling `Application.CalculateFull` before locking? Also, it it possible that you have data sources that update in the background, needing `Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone`?

Comment: Did you try refreshing the PivotTables directly, rather than through PivotCache? `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").RefreshTable`

Comment: @EmilioSilva Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone was the fix! put it before my lock commands. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was given by Emilio Silva.

In the lock module before it locks I put Application.CalculateFull and Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone.

**Module 9**

```
Public Sub lockcells()
    Application.CalculateFull
    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
    Worksheets("Batch Checker").Range("A4:N200").Locked = True
    Worksheets("Batch Checker").Protect Password:="REDacted", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
End Sub
```